# Sencha Touch 2: Works fine on browser, requests does not work wrapped in PhoneGap 1.4

Tags: ios, cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a Sencha Touch 2 app runing 100% in Chrome, but when I wrap it in PhoneGap 1.4 (For iPad2 using Xcode) the ajax requests seems not to work. Maybe I missed something in PhoneGap?

Comment: There is no issue for Ajax on PhoneGap, it's all the same with PhoneGap or not. Can you show more details? Or you can alert/console.log some message in ajax's callback to tell if the ajax request was successfully sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because of  iOS security restriction. Add your Domain to the Whitelist!
http://davehiren.blogspot.de/2012/03/whitelist-rejection-error-in-xcode-for.html

To your comment:

```
<key>ExternalHosts</key>
<array>
    <string>negroesquisso.pt</string>
</array>
```

Comment: Ok, I have to add my domain to the whitelist. But I have no GUI for this XML, can you help me with the tags?

Comment: add the host in PhoneGap.plist under the "ExternalHosts" key

Comment: Yes, I've located the file and proprieties. Thank you.

Comment: <key>ExternalHosts</key>
    <string>negroesquisso.pt</string> Should be like this? This gives me a error

Comment: Well, edit it in xcode... https://img.skitch.com/20120424-b68pa47f6qh8n4t9wge5i717g9.jpg